# Ethernet connection won't reach wall sockets - ( Router -> Switch -> Laptops)

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I am new to this forum and I hope that I will get the help that I need.
I am setting up my home network which looks like below.

So I want to connect a router through a switch to all the wall ethernet sockets I have in the house (red points in the diagram).

I am encountering an issue where whenever I connect a laptop to a wall socket (within blue rectangle) I get no connection. All the wall sockets are connected with a RJ45 cable connected by me. Both ends of each cable/wall socket respect the T-568B standard.

What is the problem? All the cables are connected the same and the switch is a common 5-ports plug-and-play switch which requires no additional configuration.

EDIT: I checked all the cables with the cable tester and something interesting came up.

This is the test I did:

**Main part of tester** <- ethernet cable -> **wall socket** <- ethernet cable -> **remote part of tester**

I did this test to all 4 ethernet cables that reach the switch and the tester does not show anything for each of them.

Does anybody have any idea if I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

[Home Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYj85.png)

Comment: It sure does not sound like these are terminated using T-568B standard or the jacks terminate elsewhere.  What happens when you try Main part of tester <- Ethernet cable -> remote part of tester?  (ie to ensure the tester works the way you think it does)

Comment: This test works ok, all the lights light up from 1 to 8 and G.

Answer (score 1):

There is a finite number of reasons for what's happening here, you should double- or triple-check these to find the actual culprit.

1. You are mistaken and the cables are not actually terminated using the same standard (T-568B). It's easy to mistake them, especially on some punch-downs.
2. The termination standard is correct, but the cables were improperly or poorly terminated (loose connections). If it's your first time punching down CAT5/6 or terminating RJ45 connectors this is very likely.
3. The cables are defective or were otherwise damaged when they were pulled. One or more conductors in the cable could be bad causing the connection to not be established (or the cable length/distance is too large - more than 100m).
4. You have some wires "crossed" - i.e. the cables you think are going to the wall jacks from the switch actually go elsewhere (or vice versa). This is more likely if you are reusing old cabling rather than with new runs you've just made.
5. The ports you are using are disabled or broken - make sure you can connect to the switch via the ports you are plugging the cable runs into. Likewise, make sure the ethernet jacks on the laptop(s) function properly when connected to a known-good switch.

Comment: Thanks Sam! I'll check these steps one more time to make sure everything is ok. Just one question though. I saw that If I plug only one end of the cable to the main part of the cable tester the leds start to light up. Does that mean that I can use the main part of the tester to check every single end of the cables, one at a time?

Comment: @SamueleMilan Depending on what kind of tester you have... I'm assuming you have a simple one that just checks for continuity on each of the eight conductors in the cable. I have a similar one - it sequences through conductors 1-8 in order on the "main" end. You have to connect the other end of the tester to the opposite end of the same cable. The test is successful if you see the lights 1-8 on the remote end of the tester light up in order as they do on the main end. Does your tester function this way or is it another type?

Comment: I have the same tester.
https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Tester-Network-Ethernet-Shield/dp/B08TRDRHCG/ref=sr_1_4?c=ts&keywords=Network+%26+Cable+Testers&qid=1701213008&s=industrial&sr=1-4&ts_id=7701919011